# Search in MySQL+PHP by bit status

Tags: php, mysql, search, compare, bit

Ive been triying to do this for a whole day without any luck.

A quick explanation: I have this gaming system where we match if someone is able to do an attack or not by searching on his abilities field.

```
To be able to use the "flame" skill you need to "know" how to do it, it requires the 7th and the 1st bit ON (10 bits): 0000000101

And this would be a player "knowledge" field where we put 1s if they did some work before (10 bits where 1st bit is fire, second bit is ice, third bit is sorcery and so on): 0010110101
```

My problem starts when I try to compare if a player "knows" or not that skill since I haven't been able to just compare if the 1st or 3rd bit are ON or OFF.

This would be the ideal example:

Fire skill: XXXXXXX1X1
Knowledge: 1X1XX1X1X1

On this example the player would be able to do the @fire attack@ because his first and third bit are ON even tho the player "knows" many other things (10th,8TH,5TH ARE ON TOO)

Splitting everything onto 10 different fields is not an option since its already working and would require loads of work to change everything else.

I hope you can help me, 1st time asking but years using stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just get the 2 positions you need? like knowledge[0] and knowledge[2] and if both are 1 he can use fire.

Comment: you can use masks, @Barmar answer, if you already have the 10bits for the skill you want use. If you only have the positions then checking on the knowledge the exatc positions is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test whether all the bits in a mask are on, use:

```
WHERE abilities & b'000000101' = b'000000101'
```

To test whether any of the bits are on, use:

```
WHERE abilities & b'000000101' != 0
```

To turn on all the bits in the mask:

```
SET abilities = abilities | b'000000101'
```

To turn them all off:

```
SET abilities = abilities & ~b'000000101'
```

These bit functions are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-functions.html)

Comment: Hi there, this would be fine if I were looking to know if a player can use certain ability, but If I wanted to list all the players that can use certain ability, how could I do it? I want MySql to check all the players that has the second and third bit ON. THANKS.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `Players` WHERE `Abilities` & b'0000000001' This will pull everything ending on 1, but If I do & b'0000000111' will also pull everything with 1 in first,second and third bit (which I dont want)

Comment: SELECT * FROM Players WHERE Abilities & b'0000000001'=b'0000000001' will select the ones with the last bit on no matter which other bits were on

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can compare bits by

```
SELECT (b'0000000101' & b'1010010101')
```

For example.

So to test if a player knows ice, you could do a bitwise and with `b'0000000010`

Of course, if the number of skills exceeds the number of available bits, you will need to change things.

Either bite the bullet and add the extra fields, or make the binary field in the table larger by using a larger data type.

This second option may require some work  converting the old data types to the new.

Comment: Hi! could I just do something like this= SELECT * FROM table WHERE player meets ability. By this I would like to echo(in php) every player that can use fire (first bit). At the moment if I use my MySQL query I will bring only the players that can use fire, but if the player knew ice, it wont. I guess im just comparing integers.

My current query: SELECT * FROM players WHERE ability=0000000001